# how can I set my new new terminal to retain session of previous terminals?

Tags: linux, terminal, gnome-terminal

In linux, (on my mac, i can do this in the settings in iterm2) how can I set up my terminal emulator so that my session is maintained for each new terminal I open?

eg: if I am in `~/code/` folder in my terminal, the I open a new terminal, i should be in the `~/code/` folder in the new terminal too, not `~/`

my usecase is that I don't lose context when working with i3

is there a setting or a recommended emulator that can do this, is it possible to complete this implementation programmatically?

Comment: Why flagging this? It can be solved with programming.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis Voting to reopen

Comment: @Inder: Write-a-program-for-me is NOT a *programming* question, thus it is still **off-topic** on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I reconsidered my opinion and I agree with you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to do this, as you can simply reach a "frequently" `cd`ed directory by searching in the history of commands.

However, if you really want to do it, one (dirty?) trick would be adding this in your `.bashrc`:

```sh
# this is in ~/.bashrc
exit() {
  sed -i '${
            /^cd /{c\cd '"$PWD
          "'q};a\cd '"$PWD
          }" $HOME/.bashrc
  command exit
}
```

What it does is (implicitly) printing all lines up to and including the *second to last line*, then on the last line (`$`) it checks if the last line starts with `cd` followed by space; if it does, it `c`hanges it to `cd $PWD` and `q`uits; if it doesn't, the `cd $PWD` line is _`a`appended.